# How to deserialize named arrays into objects in Kafka

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, jackson

Here is the example of my received kafka message:

```
{"target":[{"timestamp": "2022-06-20T12:31:46+03:00", "result":"fail", "message":"Client not found."}, {"timestamp": "2022-06-25T12:31:46+03:00", "result":"success"}], "xxi":[{"timestamp": "2022-06-25T12:31:46+03:00", "result":"success"}]}
```

Here is the class which is for objects to deserialize from the message

```
public class CommonEventResult {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private String result;
    private String message;
}
```

The main problem that I don't know what the name of a system will come - `xxi`, `target`, etc.
But I want to deserialize the message in some `CommonEventResult[]` array or something like that. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model your response class with some generic implementation, something like

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)

public class DataResponse {

    public String dataResult;

    public String getDataResult() {
        return dataResult;
    }
}


class GenericResponse implements Response<List<**DataResponse**>> {

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<DataResponse> data;


    @Override
    public List<DataResponse> getData() {
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the Response interface defined?

Comment: That would be an interface, you can have something like this. 

public interface Response<T> {
 public T getData();
}

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Map<String,List<CommonEventResult>>
```

Comment: If I use your variant, it deserializes to Map<String, List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>

Comment: @МаксимРыбалкин The list is needed, yes